# I want to add a circular ripple hover effect on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I want to add a ripple effect animation when hovering over an image. I have a link which he uses ripple effect on button by using JavaScript which i have no idea how it work but i want to use the same method over an image on my code.
https://codepen.io/ViktorKorolyuk/pen/GYGwpv

Above Link shows the ripple effect on button and below is my  code with blur effect with no animation at all.So I just want to add a ripple effect using the same method but on image

```
<html>
<div class="row">
<div class="column">

    <div class="div-with-image-and-text">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column half">

       <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    <div class="column half">

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div></div>

      <div class="text"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"style="text- 
      decoration:none"><h1 style="color:white;">Architecture</h1></a></div>
      </div>

      <div class="div-with-image-and-text">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="column half">

       <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
       </div>
      <div class="column half">

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div></div>

      <div class="text"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"style="text- 
      decoration:none"><h1 style="color:white;">Architecture</h1></a></div>
     </div>
      </div>
      <!--Second container-->

     <div class="column">

     <div class="div-with-image-and-text">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="column half">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"> 
   </div>
    <div class="column half">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"> 
     </div></div>

      <div class="text"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"style="text- 
  decoration:none"><h1 style="color:white;">Landscape</h1></a></div>
  </div>

 <div class="div-with-image-and-text">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column half">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"> 
    </div>
    <div class="column half">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%"> 
     </div></div>

      <div class="text"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"style="text- 
     decoration:none"><h1 style="color:white;">Landscape</h1></a></div>
     </div>
     </html>

     <style>
     * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
       }

     body {
     margin: 0;
     font-family: Arial;
      }

     .header {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 32px;
      }

    .row {
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     padding: 0 4px;
      }

     .column {
     -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
      flex: 25%;
      max-width: 50%;
     padding: 0 4px;
     }

     .column.half {
    -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE10 */
     flex: 50%;
     max-width: 50%;
     padding: 0 4px;
      }

      .column img {
      margin-top: 8px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100%;
      }

       @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .column {
       -ms-flex: 50%;
       flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
           }
        }

       @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .column {
      -ms-flex: 100%;
      flex: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
         }
       }

       .div-with-image-and-text{
       position: relative;
         }
       .div-with-image-and-text .text {
       display:none;
        }

       .div-with-image-and-text:hover img{
         filter: blur(3px) brightness(40%);
         opacity: 0.5;
         transform: scale(0.98);
         box-shadow: none;
           }
          .div-with-image-and-text:hover .text{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
              top: 50%;left: 50%;
            transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
           text-align:center;
            font-family: 'Muli';
            color:white;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-shadow:0 0 10px gray;
              }
```

Comment: do you want your mouse effect hover stay after ripple effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way give you ripple effect without your effect that you give with hover

first make a html file and write this code

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainRow">
      <div class="display">
        <a class="HOVER">
          <span></span>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="text">
          <a
            href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
            style="text-decoration:none"
          >
            <h1 style="color:white;">Architecture</h1>
          </a>
        </div> -->
        </a>
        <a class="HOVER">
          <span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="text">
          <a
            href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
            style="text-decoration:none"
          >
            <h1 style="color:white;">Architecture</h1>
          </a>
        </div> -->
        </a>
        <a class="HOVER">
          <span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="text">
          <a
            href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
            style="text-decoration:none"
          >
            <h1 style="color:white;">Landscape</h1></a
          >
        </div> -->
        </a>
        <a class="HOVER FLASH">
          <span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="text">
            <a
              href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
              style="text-decoration:none"
            >
              <h1 style="color:white;">Landscape</h1>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

anf after that make a css file behind your html file and write this code in cssFile

> index.css

```css
/* @keyframes shake {
  25% {
    transform: rotate(calc(var(--angle) * -1));
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
} */

html {
  font: 100 1.5em sans-serif;
}
body {
  padding: 2em 5em 0em 5em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.display {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: 0.1em;
  /* width: 50%; */
}

.HOVER {
  --width: 100%;
  --time: 0.7s;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* height: 18em; */
  /* padding: 1em; */

  color: white;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.HOVER:hover {
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}

.HOVER text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: color var(--time);
}

.HOVER:hover text {
  color: #222;
}
.HOVER span {
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  z-index: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: width var(--time), padding-top var(--time);
}

.HOVER:hover span {
  width: calc(var(--width) * 2.25);
  padding-top: calc(var(--width) * 2.25);
}

.HOVER.FLASH:hover text {
  color: white;
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(40%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Muli";
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}
.HOVER.FLASH span {
  background: #ff3b3b;
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(40%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.animated {
  --angle: 5deg;
  animation: shake 0.3s;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}
.mainRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column.half {
  -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.div-with-image-and-text {
  position: relative;
}
.div-with-image-and-text .text {
  display: none;
}

.div-with-image-and-text:hover img {
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(40%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: none;
}
.div-with-image-and-text:hover .text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Muli";
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainRow">
      <div class="display">
        <a class="HOVER">
          <span></span>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="text">
          <a
            href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
            style="text-decoration:none"
          >
            <h1 style="color:white;">Architecture</h1>
          </a>
        </div> -->
        </a>
        <a class="HOVER">
          <span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="text">
          <a
            href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
            style="text-decoration:none"
          >
            <h1 style="color:white;">Architecture</h1>
          </a>
        </div> -->
        </a>
        <a class="HOVER">
          <span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="text">
          <a
            href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
            style="text-decoration:none"
          >
            <h1 style="color:white;">Landscape</h1></a
          >
        </div> -->
        </a>
        <a class="HOVER FLASH">
          <span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column half">
              <img
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
                style="width:100%"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="text">
            <a
              href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg"
              style="text-decoration:none"
            >
              <h1 style="color:white;">Landscape</h1>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
html {
  font: 100 1.5em sans-serif;
}
body {
  padding: 2em 5em 0em 5em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.display {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: 0.1em;
  /* width: 50%; */
}

.HOVER {
  --width: 100%;
  --time: 0.7s;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* height: 18em; */
  /* padding: 1em; */

  color: white;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.HOVER text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: color var(--time);
}

.HOVER:hover text {
  color: #222;
}
.HOVER span {
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  z-index: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: width var(--time), padding-top var(--time);
}

.HOVER:hover span {
  width: calc(var(--width) * 2.25);
  padding-top: calc(var(--width) * 2.25);
}

.HOVER.FLASH:hover text {
  color: white;
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(40%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Muli";
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}
.HOVER.FLASH span {
  background: #ff3b3b;
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(40%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.animated {
  --angle: 5deg;
  animation: shake 0.3s;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}
.mainRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column.half {
  -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.div-with-image-and-text {
  position: relative;
}
.div-with-image-and-text .text {
  display: none;
}

.div-with-image-and-text:hover img {
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(40%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: none;
}
.div-with-image-and-text:hover .text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Muli";
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the image blur instead of white and the blur thing should go along with the the cursor as  we move to the next one...Thank you by the way!

Comment: yes its also possible to make the image blur instead of white @RandomNoobDeveloper

Comment: now i've turned my code with blur hover my friend. now test it @RandomNoobDeveloper

Comment: Is there a way to make the image- blur animation instead of  white animation?

Comment: Your wellcome my friend.Yes it is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS solution for the Ripple Effect:

A working example: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/i3HhQVIzlbq5QzGM?preview

**HTML**

```
<div class="ripple-effect-container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ripple-effect-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  background-color: #063458;
}

.ripple-effect-container:hover {
  background: #063458 radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, #063458 1%) center/15000%;
}
.ripple-effect-container:active {
  background-color: #6eb9f7;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}

.ripple-effect-container img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.ripple-effect-container img {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```